# Azure Forms Recognizer Prebuilt-Invoice crashes during processing a file with "Name or service not known"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, podman, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to run the Microsoft Cognitive Services Form Recognizer on premise.
While the general layout analyzer works fine for me, the FR for the invoice model is constantly crashing:

The error message is:

```
fail: formrecognizerinvoice[0]
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
```

or in detail:

```
status: SERVING
fail: formrecognizerinvoice[0]
      Unhandled exception in OcrHandlerService. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
         at  .․. (HttpContent , Dictionary`2 , RequestCorrelation , Details , CancellationToken )
         at  .․. (OcrVerticalQueueMessage , RequestCorrelation , CancellationToken )
         at  .․. (OcrVerticalQueueMessage , CancellationToken ) Time='12/22/2022 9:35:57 AM' EventId='Error' requestId='ddc2246b-2d15-42c5-807a-17e1e1591ed0' hostId='MSFR3_pod' serviceName='formrecognizerinvoice' methodName='Process' sourceLineNumber='170' sourceFilePath='/source/src/OcrHandler/Handler/OcrHandler.cs' errorCode='1204' errorCode Description='Unhandled exception happened during running OCR handler.'
fail: formrecognizerinvoice[0]
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at  .․. (OcrVerticalQueueMessage , CancellationToken )
         at  .⁎. . .MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.Storage.QueueManager.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<RegisterConcurrentWorkScheduler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.Storage.ConcurrentWorkScheduler`1.Work(T item, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) Time='12/22/2022 9:35:57 AM' EventId='Error' requestId='ddc2246b-2d15-42c5-807a-17e1e1591ed0' hostId='MSFR3_pod' serviceName='formrecognizerinvoice' methodName='Work' sourceLineNumber='138' sourceFilePath='/source/src/Common/Storage/Queue/Worker/ConcurrentWorkScheduler.cs' errorCode='1217' errorCode Description='Unhandled exception happened in queue worker.'
fail: formrecognizerinvoice[0]
      Unhandled exception in OcrHandlerService. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
         at  .․. (HttpContent , Dictionary`2 , RequestCorrelation , Details , CancellationToken )
         at  .․. (OcrVerticalQueueMessage , RequestCorrelation , CancellationToken )
         at  .․. (OcrVerticalQueueMessage , CancellationToken ) Time='12/22/2022 9:35:58 AM' EventId='Error' requestId='ddc2246b-2d15-42c5-807a-17e1e1591ed0' hostId='MSFR3_pod' serviceName='formrecognizerinvoice' methodName='Process' sourceLineNumber='170' sourceFilePath='/source/src/OcrHandler/Handler/OcrHandler.cs' errorCode='1204' errorCode Description='Unhandled exception happened during running OCR handler.'
fail: formrecognizerinvoice[0]
      System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at  .․. (OcrVerticalQueueMessage , CancellationToken )
         at  .⁎. . .MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.Storage.QueueManager.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<RegisterConcurrentWorkScheduler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.CloudAI.Containers.Storage.ConcurrentWorkScheduler`1.Work(T item, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) Time='12/22/2022 9:35:58 AM' EventId='Error' requestId='ddc2246b-2d15-42c5-807a-17e1e1591ed0' hostId='MSFR3_pod' serviceName='formrecognizerinvoice' methodName='Work' sourceLineNumber='138' sourceFilePath='/source/src/Common/Storage/Queue/Worker/ConcurrentWorkScheduler.cs' errorCode='1217' errorCode Description='Unhandled exception happened in queue worker.'
```

I was using a yaml file to run the container with

```
sudo podman play kube ./rech_container_only.yaml
```

```
# Created with podman-3.4.7
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-12-22T08:56:40Z"
  labels:
    app: xxxx
  name: xxxx
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - ./run.sh
    - eula=accept
    - Billing=https://frxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/
    - ApiKey=XXXXX
    env:
    - name: EULA
      value: accept
    - name: Billing
      value: https://frxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/
    - name: ApiKey
      value: xxxx
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/invoice:latest
    name: xxxx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5050
      hostPort: 5005
    securityContext:
      capabilities: {}
    stdin: true
    tty: true
```

The general service status is okay:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5005/status" -H  "accept: application/json"
{"service":"formrecognizerinvoice","apiStatus":"Valid","apiStatusMessage":"Api Key is valid, no action needed."}
```

The call on the api was done via curl command:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5005/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze"
-H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"source\":\"https://rechnungen-muster.de/images/musterrechnung-6p.jpg\"}"
```

No response to the stdout has been written but on

```
sudo podman logs -l
```

Comment: Quick question - sorry if it's not linked, but I got a doubt and not enough used to containerized version of those service: I'm wondering if you should use "5050" port instead of 5005 given your config file

Comment: On the doc page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/containers/form-recognizer-container-configuration?view=form-recog-2.1.0#example-docker-composeyml-file, you can see in the section under "Receipt and OCR Read containers" that the example connects outer port 5000 to 5050 internally.

I have changed my outer port to 5005, but that should not matter. I am going to try to run a similar scenario on my side, tomorrow. Perhaps the prebuilt-containers need the computer vision container to work properly?

Comment: As a secondary approach, I am going to get fott-2-1 running, too:

    https://github.com/microsoft/OCR-Form-Tools